# Adding empty number of rows in gridview based on grid rows count

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Hi  i am looking for having 10 records in the grid-view by default

so if the grid-view has 3 rows then there are 7 empty rows to add,

if grid-view has 4 rows then there are 6 empty rows, etc..

also if grid-view has 10 rows there's no empty rows to add

```
QueryClass q = new QueryClass();
grid.DataSource = q.getdata();
grid.DataBind();
```

**Method**

```
public DataTable getdata()
{
string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP(10) * FROM Store");
return Search(query);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an extension method for this:

```
public static class HelperMethod
{
    public static List<QueryClassObj> Extend(this List<QueryClassObj> items)
    {
        while (items.Count < 10)
        {
            items.Add(new QueryClassObj());
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

When you get the data and bind to your grid simply:

```
QueryClass q = new QueryClass();
grid.DataSource = q.getdata().Extend();
grid.DataBind();
```

Based on your edit you can try this

```
public DataTable getdata()
{
string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP(10) * FROM Store");
DataTable results= Search(query);
while(results.Rows.Count<10)
{
 results.Rows.Add(results.NewRow());
}
}
```

Sorry I have not been able to test my last edit as I'm away from PC

Comment: thanks but i didn't understand  how  to add extension method  i added the method  i used in question

Comment: @Ayman Replace QueryClassObj with the type of object that your q.getdata() returns

Comment: system.data.datatable does not contain a definition for Extend accepting a first argument of type system.data.datatable

Comment: @Ayman See my edit. The original answer was posted before you showed the getdata()

Answer (score 1):

You can Add the missing items to your datasource:

```
QueryClass q = new QueryClass();

var dSource = q.getdata();

foreach (var missing in Enumerable.Range(1, 10 - dSource.Rows.Count))
{
    dSource.NewRow();
}
grid.DataSource = dSource;

grid.DataBind();
```